# How to set values in JavaScript (Highcharts) using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have the following present in `chart.js`:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
```

I have a table called `monthly_flagged` which stores the total amount of flagged posts for each month. I am trying to create a line chart to show the fluctuation between number of flagged posts every month.

Using PHP I have got the following data:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM monthly_flagged");
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$get_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($statement);
    $month          = $get_data['month'];
    $year           = $get_data['year'];
    $total_flaggged = $get_data['total_flagged'];
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
```

The thing is, I am unsure on how I can apply this data to JS. Assume my `monthly_flagged` table has one row:

```
id:1
month: April
year: 2016
total_flagged:28
```

Using the data obtained in `$month` and `$total_flagged`, I want to update the `Apr` on my x-axis.

Currently, this is how data is displayed (using test numbers):

```
series: [{
            name: 'Flagged posts',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }
```

But I basically need it to go something like this:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Flagged posts',
            data: [$monthJan, $monthFeb, $monthApr, ...]
        }
```

But again, unsure how to do this.

Comment: if a variable such as - $monthApr is to be stored, where is it being created in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing your data in an array,

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM monthly_flagged");
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$months = array();
$data = array();
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);
while($get_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
    $months[]          = $get_data['month'];
    $data[]            = $get_data['total_flagged'];
}
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
```

Then on your javascript:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [<?php echo json_encode($months); ?>]
},
```

And finally:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Flagged posts',
            data: [<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>]
        }
```

Comment: Hi. First of all, thank you for your answer. I'm just wondering if using `<?php ?>` tags is valid in JavaScript? The JavaScript is in a file called `charts.js`. Using `[<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>]` does not work (the whole chart disappears). Is there a way to use `<?php ?>` in JavaScript?

Comment: You can change it to a php file, for example chart.php and still include it as javascript <script src="chart.php"></script>. If you wish to maintain chart.js, you can store them in a javascript variable inside your php file.

Comment: Ah! It's showing the graph now, with data from the database! I cannot thank you enough! Appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I just thoroughly tested this approach. In my database, I now how two rows, for April 2016 & January 2016. April has `21` flagged posts, whereas January has `51 flagged posts. In my x-axis, when I had one row in my table (April), "April" was displayed in text, and the line graph showed `21`. Now that I have two rows, the number `2` is appearing on my x-axis with the value of `51` - It isn't even showing the data for April?

Comment: can you provide a sample select query data?

Comment: Hi Dom, no worries, I have resolved the issue now, everything works great! :) Thank's again!